# Powershell convert a variable to utf-16

Tags: powershell, variables, utf-16

I am struggling to import a csv file  making all content a variable then turn only one of the variables into utf-16.
I have everything else just struggling to convert it in the following format:

Example needing to convert the word `Hello World` to `00480065006c006c006f00057006f0072006c0064`.

The script would look similar to this.

```
$text = "Hello World"::UTF16

$text
```

Is this even possible? Or is there a way to convert it?

Comment: Are you trying to import data from a UTF-16 encoded CSV file, but PowerShell is using the wrong encoding so corrupting characters?  If so, use the Encoding parameter on the `Import-CSV` Cmdlet: `Import-Csv -Path '.\Path\To\MyFile.csv' -Encoding Unicode`.  If that's not the case, please can you provide more info on what problem you're trying to fix / what's not doing as you'd expect from a functional perspective?

Answer (score 5):

The output you desire is the hex representation of UTF-16 Big Endian encoding, known as [BigEndianUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode?view=netframework-4.8).

You can create a helper function that converts a string to that:

```
function ConvertTo-Utf16BE {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$String
    )
    $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode
    ($enc.GetBytes($string) | ForEach-Object {'{0:X2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
}

'Hello World' | ConvertTo-Utf16BE
```

Output:

> 00480065006C006C006F00200057006F0072006C0064

Comment: Very clean solution.

Comment: Very nice. I might add a `LowerCase` switch (or vice versa)

Comment: @Theo how to do the same the in Little-endian UTF-16 format?

Comment: @Linga just use `$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` for that