# How to convert cyrillic into utf16

Tags: json, powershell, escaping, utf-16

tl;dr Is there a way to convert cyrillic stored in hashtable into UTF-16?
Like `кириллица` into `\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430`

I need to import file, parse it into `id` and `value` then convert it into .json and now im struggling to find a way to convert `value` into utf codes.

And yes, it is needed that way

cyrillic.txt:

```
1 кириллица
```

PH:

```
clear-host
foreach ($line in (Get-Content C:\Users\users\Downloads\cyrillic.txt)){
    $nline = $line.Split(' ', 2)
    $properties = @{
        'id'= $nline[0] #stores "1" from file
        'value'=$nline[1] #stores "кириллица" from file
    }
    $temp+=New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
$temp | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\data.json"
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id":  "1",
        "value":  "кириллица"
    },
]
```

Needed:

```
[
    {
        "id":  "1",
        "value":  "\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430"
    },
]
```

At this point as a newcomer to PH i have no idea even how to search for it properly

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSVersionTable['PSVersion'] -as [string]`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695690/powershell-convert-a-variable-to-utf-16

Comment: `([char[]]"кириллица").ForEach{ '\u{0:x4}' -f [uint] $_} -join ""`. But this is admittedly an oversimplification that might not work so well if surrogates are thrown into the mix (emojis and whatnot). Integrating this with `ConvertTo-Json` is also not really possible (it would start escaping the backslashes), so you'd have to build the JSON manually, which is not very attractive.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 5.1.17763.2268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s helpful comment, the following works robustly, assuming that the input file contains no `NUL` characters (which is usually a safe assumption for *text* files):

```
# Sample value pair; loop over file lines omitted for brevity.
$nline = '1 кириллица'.Split(' ', 2)

$properties = [ordered] @{
  id = $nline[0]
  # Insert aux. NUL characters before the 4-digit hex representations of each
  # code unit, to be removed later.
  value = -join ([uint16[]] [char[]] $nline[1]).ForEach({ "`0{0:x4}" -f $_ })
}

# Convert to JSON, then remove the escaped representations of the aux. NUL chars.,
# resulting in proper JSON escape sequences.
# Note: ... | Out-File ... omitted.
(ConvertTo-Json @($properties)) -replace '\\u0000', '\u'
```

Output (pipe to `ConvertFrom-Json` to verify that it works):

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "value": "\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430"
  }
]
```

Explanation:

- `[uint16[]] [char[]] $nline[1]` converts the `[char]` instances of the strings stored in `$nline[1]` into the underlying UTF-16 code units (a .NET `[char]` is an unsigned 16-bit integer encoding a Unicode code point).

  - Note that this works even with Unicode characters that have code points above `0xFFFF`, i.e. that are too large to fit into a `[uint16]`. Such characters outside the so-called BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), e.g. , are simply represented as *pairs* of UTF-16 code units, so-called *surrogate pairs*, which a JSON processor should recognize ([`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) does).
  - However, on *Windows* such chars. may not *render* correctly, depending on your console window's font. The safest option is to use [*Windows Terminal*](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), available [in the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal)
- The call to the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) processes each resulting code unit:

  - `` "`0{0:x4}" -f $_ `` uses an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) to create a string that starts with a `NUL` character (`` "`0" ``), followed by a 4-digit hex. representation (`x4`) of the code unit at hand, created via `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).

    - This trick of replacing what should *ultimately* be a verbatim `\u` prefix *temporarily* with a `NUL` character is needed, because a verbatim `\` embedded in a string value would invariably be *doubled* in its JSON representation, given that `\` acts the escape character in JSON.
  - The result is something like `"<NUL>043a"`, which [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) transforms as follows, given that it must escape each `NUL` character as `\u0000`:

    ```
    "\u0000043a"
    ```
- The result from `ConvertTo-Json` can then be transformed into the desired escape sequences simply by replacing `\u0000` (escaped as `\\u0000` for use with the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) oeprator) with `\u`, e.g.:

  ```
    "\u0000043a" -replace '\\u0000', '\u' # -> "\u043a", i.e. к
  ```

Comment: I actually had to consult the standard to confirm that `Convert-Json` wasn't just being overly nice with allowing the `NUL`s, but no, the standard explicitly allows all characters, including all control characters, as long as they're escaped. (In the unlikely case the file does contain `NUL` we could stick in a sequence guaranteed not to occur, like a fresh GUID, but that seems like overkill.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @JeroenMostert. Good idea re GUID, should `NUL` chars. really be present in the input. As for non-BMP characters: I think they're handled fine too - please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a simpler way of doing this, but this could work for you:

```
$temp = foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\users\Downloads\cyrillic.txt')){
    $nline = $line.Split(' ', 2)
    # output an object straight away so it gets collected in variable $temp
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        id    = $nline[0]   #stores "1" from file
        value = (([system.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes($nline[1]) | 
                ForEach-Object {'{0:x2}' -f $_ }) -join '' -split '(.{4})' -ne '' | 
                ForEach-Object { '\u{0}' -f $_ }) -join ''
    }
}
($temp | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '\\\\u', '\u' | Out-File 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\data.json'
```

Simpler using `.ToCharArray()`:

```
$temp = foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\users\Downloads\cyrillic.txt')){
    $nline = $line.Split(' ', 2)
    # output an object straight away so it gets collected in variable $temp
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        id    = $nline[0]   #stores "1" from file
        value = ($nline[1].ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {'\u{0:x4}' -f [uint16]$_ }) -join ''
    }
}
($temp | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '\\\\u', '\u' | Out-File 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\data.json'
```

Value `"кириллица"` will be converted to `\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way simply saving it to a utf16be file and then reading out the bytes, and formatting it, skipping the first 2 bytes, which is the bom (\ufeff).  $_ didn't work by itself.  Note that there's *two* utf16 encodings that have different byte orders, big endian and little endian.  The range of cyrillic is U+0400..U+04FF.  Added -nonewline.

```
'кириллица' | set-content utf16be.txt -encoding BigEndianUnicode -nonewline
$list = get-content utf16be.txt -Encoding Byte -readcount 2 | 
  % { '\u{0:x2}{1:x2}' -f $_[0],$_[1] } | select -skip 1
-join $list

\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430
```